# Why are my unit tests not working?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I have a fairly trivial Grails unit test:

```
@TestFor(DateTimeTagLib)
class DateTimeTagLibSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "showTime"() {
        assertEquals "14:26", new DateTimeTagLib().showTime(value: DateTime.parse("2013-01-01 14:26:00")).toString()
    }
}
```

When I try to launch it with 'Run' from my IntelliJ Idea 13 EAP I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin.shutdownApplicationContext(GrailsUnitTestMixin.groovy:266)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension$FixtureType$FixtureMethodInterceptor.intercept(JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension.java:145)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

The line in question in GrailsUnitTestMixin is:

```
     static void shutdownApplicationContext() {
         if (applicationContext.isActive()) { <-- this one
```

When I launch it with `grails test-app unit:` or `grails test-app :spock` I get:

```
| Tests PASSED - view reports in C:\projects\MyProject\target\test-reports
```

However - the reports there actually show `No tests executed.`, despite the fact that the test is in `/test/unit/mypackage/` where it was automatically created by Grails. If I add a print statement into the test it also doesn't get executed.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit - Burt Beckwith suggested my unit test is wrong. He's right, but that doesn't actually fully solve the problem I'm having :/

```
    void "showTime"() {
        given:
            print 'executing'
            def taglib = new DateTimeTagLib()

        expect:
            "14:26" == taglib.showTime(value: DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parseDateTime("2013-01-01 14:26:00")).toString()
    }
```

gets

```
executing
java.lang.NullPointerException
at grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin.shutdownApplicationContext(GrailsUnitTestMixin.groovy:266)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension$FixtureType$FixtureMethodInterceptor.intercept(JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension.java:145)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Whether due to this or otherwise, I'm getting different behavior as well from command line `test-app :spock`.

```
grails> test-app :spock
| Error An error occurred installing the plugin [webdriver-0.4.2]: Unable to delete file C:\projects\myproject\target\work\plugins\webdriver-0.4.2\lib\webdriver-ast-transforms.jar
| Error Error running script test-app :spock: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

---

Edit #2 - commenting out webdriver in build config / restarting grails / `clean-all` helped with last issue, but `test-app :spock` still shows as "No tests executed.' in the HTML report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Spock test, and test methods have to have one or more labelled blocks to be considered test methods. Rename the class to end in "Tests" and extend GroovyTestCase (or a subclass of it) to use JUnit 3, or extend nothing to use JUnit 4. Or convert the test to Spock format:

```
void "showTime"() {
   given:
      def taglib = new DateTimeTagLib()

   expect:
      "14:26" == taglib.showTime(value: DateTime.parse("2013-01-01 14:26:00")).toString()
}
```

Comment: Burt, thanks, this is very helpful, but still doesn't actually fix my problem :(

Comment: +1: I was bitten by this today, trying to figure out why my Spock test refused to fail even with lines like "assert 1 == 2". Turned out I had no labelled blocks and Spock simply ignored it as a result. Rather frustrating...

Answer (score 1):

I hit this error when I used @TestFor on an IntegrationSpec. Instead, use:

```
class MyControllerSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    @Autowired
    MyController controller

    void "my controller does something"() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Make sure you are using Specification in the */unit* test path and IntegrationSpec in the */integration* path.